# Unity WebGL build to fullscreen on mobile devices

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, unity-webgl, mobile-devices

Does anyone know if there is a way to have a working fullscreen button on a browser on mobile devices in WebGL Unity build? I've seen some topics here that it is not supported on mobile devices, but only on tablets. But anyway it is kinda a dealbreaker for us and we need to make this work. Thanks for any response!